# I accidently deleted everything in a remote repository, and force rewrote history

Tags: git, github

I pushed a commit on a remote repository where I changed one file, but the whole directory of the file was tracked in that commit, so it made it look like I changed every file in this directory.

So, I wanted to erase that commit from the history of the remote repo, with the command git push origin +f2d3f909138e785b63415808c487abc070c4a12b^:master, f2d3f909138e785b63415808c487abc070c4a12b being the commit I wanted to get rid of.

What happened is that every other commits in the history of the remote repo got deleted.

I'd just like to go back to way things were before that last command, the commit is not that much of a problem now. 
Worse case, I have a copy of the files locally, but the history held a lot of important information still.

Comment: First fix your local git history, then push the repaired one to remote. You can use `git reflog` if you can't find the commits in your local history.

Comment: Problem is I am not the only one that pushed on this remote, and my local history only shows my own commits.

Comment: Do you see the commits in `git reflog`? If not, maybe the commits might be retrieved from someone else who'd pushed them?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a person on your team who pushed last before you made your force push. That person has all the commits in his/her local repo. So just ask that person to push the latest commit into origin/master:

```
git push -f origin [commit hash]:refs/heads/master
```

If the commit is unknown because that person fetched the latest changes and overwrote his local branch, then he can use `git reflog` to find previously checked out commits.

Or if you have a Build Server (I hope you do) that was triggered by a push, you can find the latest commit hash in the build logs. Moreover - that commit is probably still in the working directory of the CI job.

Comment: Thanks, I reached out to that person, he should be able to fix it the way you told me.